# Twilio TaskRouter - Retrieving caller number in Assigment Callback

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice, twilio-taskrouter

I'm following a tutorial on Twilio TaskRouter. I have successfully set up a workspace, workflows, activities, taskqueues and workers. Currently i am looking at this [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/twiml-queue-calls#automatically-bridging-call-to-worker) at step 3:

[image]

When my twilio number recieves an inbound call, my server returns a enqueue instruction. When a worker is reserved for my newly created task, my AssignmentCallback endpoint is hit.

My question is: How to i retrieve the phone number of the caller in my callback?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TaskRouter engineer here.

In the sections below this in the documentation referenced you should see "Attaching data to a call using Tasks". For reference, any data you plop in here will end up in the Task's `attributes`, which you can then inspect in your callback.

However, it's actually even easier than that, as the caller ID should already be there for you. Have a look at [this documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/handle-assignment-callbacks#dequeue-linked-call-tracking), which shows you the `attributes` that will be populated for you simply by using the `<Enqueue>`. In this case, I believe what you're after is `from`.